# C# Wildcard for specific amount of characters

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, wildcard, selection

I would like to select all documents which have **exact** 4 "unknown" characters at the place where the asterisk is: (for example "****" could be "2018")

```
foreach (string s in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\ExampleTitle ****.xml").Select(Path.GetFileName))
{
    // Do something!
}
```

I know the asterisk * will match every character, no matter how many characters are between the asterisk. But as described, I want to select only results with a specific amount of unknown characters.

Comment: I think you need `Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\MyUser\Documents", "ExampleTitle ????.xml")`

Comment: I accidently refreshed the site and my accept was gone, so i did it a second time. Anyway, thank you very much for the answer, it works ! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot specify wildcards in the path argument, you need to provide the path and a search pattern, see [`GetFiles(String, String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_).

The search pattern accepts two wildcards, `?` for a single char and `*` for any amount of chars. Hence, you need

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\MyUser\Documents", "ExampleTitle ????.xml")
```

If you plan to match only digits there you will have to use a regex to filter the results of `Directory.GetFiles`:

```
var fileList = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\MyUser\Documents", "*.xml")
        .Where(p => Regex.IsMatch(Path.GetFileName(p), @"^ExampleTitle [0-9]{4}\.xml$"))
        .ToList();
```

Here,  `Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\MyUser\Documents", "*.xml")` will fetch all XML files in the given folder, and those that entirely match the `ExampleTitle <4-DIGITS>.xml` pattern will be returned then with the `Where` clause.